# Python - set path to the directory in project

Tags: python, file, path, directory, save

I created a project where my `main.py` script is in root folder `Project`. I have a `utils` directory inside and I want to get the path to this directory. I made a function which saves a `.pdf` file in my utils directory:

```
with open(os.path.abspath('utils/' + self.object.object_name+ '.pdf'), 'wb') as f:
                f.write(pdf)
```

but I get an error:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/documents/office/projects/me/utils/d.pdf'

How can I change `os.path.abspath` to do it the right way?
I want to get into `utils` directory always.

Comment: `abspath` gives you the absolute path for the path provided; why would you need to change what it does, even if you could?  If you need a different directory, then provide/compute it; `abspath` won't help with that.

Comment: I think I can use `os.path.basename` or `os.path.dirname` to improve that utils directory can be call from anywhere root folder is placed

Comment: Those functions are your to extract information *about* a path, not *define* a path.

Comment: So why I got this error while using `abspath`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is defining the path. And you can keep it relative.

```
yourPath = './utils/'
yourFileName = self.object.object_name+ '.pdf'

yourFullFileName = yourPath+yourFileName
```

and finally

```
with open(yourFullFileName, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(pdf)
```

**UPDATE**

Following the small course Scott Hunter gave me, (cf his comment) I make amends. It follows that the correct way to build your path is :

```
working_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)# __file__ is the full name of your working script
yourFullFileName = os.path.join(working_dir, 'util', self.object.object_name + "." + 'pdf')
```

By doing so, there is no assumption about the (operating-system dependent) separator.

Comment: That's not how you should build paths, and `./utils` and `utils` are equivalent (assuming, which you shouldn't, that `/` is the path separator).

Comment: @ScottHunter. By "assuming, [...], that `/` is the path separator", do you mean that i should use `os.sep` ? I thought that the forward slash character was always working when used in relative paths, for any os whatsoever. Is this not the case ?